# redirect traffic to a url in a different subnet with node

Tags: node.js, http-tunneling

i have a `computer1` with ip `192.168.10.1` subnet `255.255.255.0` without internet access
another `computer2` with ip  `192.168.1.1` subnet `255.255.255.0`
a `router1` with ip `192.168.1.200` and `192.168.10.200`
a `router2` with ip `192.168.1.254` connected on internet
what i want to do is from wan reach computer1 and access the url `192.168.10.1/xyz/urlxyz.html` the problem is that i want a free access only for the urls with `/xyz/` so i was thinking to use some kind of redirect from `computer2` to `computer1` like that

```
app.get('/xyz/',function(req,res){
      request.get("http://192.168.10.1"+req.originalUrl).on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }).pipe(res);
}); //request is a deprecated library
```

this partially works but doesn't send all the headers and other data and the site output errors, is possible to do something like that without use a proxy or vpn or something to add on the computer in the wan ? i don't want give a full access to the subnet `192.168.10.x` or the other services on the `computer1`
*note* i already use that code for access another url and that works since i access a printer and just send the data i need to print

Answer (score 0):

you can use Axios to pass header and body data for your requirements. And also you can add a limit in the header and response.